# Why is this kotlin assignment possible (switchButton.isChecked = true)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning to develop android apps in kotlin. I am using android studio 4.0.1. I dragged a switch onto a layout and set its state to true by default with

switch.setChecked(true)

But the IDE suggested I change it to

```
switch.isChecked()
```

, which wasn't what I wanted. Then I just happened to enter

```
switch.isChecked = true
```

and it worked.
My question is isChecked is a function and we don't invoke it that way. But somehow this worked. Why?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quote from [Calling Java code from Kotlin: Getters and Setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters
> (no-argument methods with names starting with `get` and single-argument
> methods with names starting with `set`) are represented as properties in
> Kotlin. `Boolean` accessor methods (where the name of the getter starts
> with `is` and the name of the setter starts with `set`) are represented as
> properties which have the same name as the getter method.

Since `Switch` is a class created in Java and has `setChecked` and `isChecked` methods, Kotlin can synthesize an `isChecked` property for you so that accessing it from Kotlin can feel more idiomatic:

```
switch.isChecked = true
println(switch.isChecked) // prints "true"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope Google will get rid of Java soon.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think Java is going away any time soon, Android SDK is a huge framework and rewriting it in Kotlin is a lot of work. It's also redundant given that the interop between Java and Kotlin is really good.